# WP Shortcode get_template_directory_uri()

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Всем привет! Ребята, возможно есть какой-то **стандартный** shortcode в WP с помощью которого можно было бы узнать путь к теме?

Или таковых нету? :)

Comment: Нет такого шорткода. Написать его самому - 3 строчки. Зачем он вам воообще нужен? Похоже, вы не с той стороны решаете задачу.

Answer (score 0):

В Wordpress есть функция get_template_directory() которая указывает путь к теме.